# Is this problem in P? Given a bipartite graph, find a minimum cardinality set of edges which intersect every vertex cover

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, np-hardness

This problem came up in my study of digraphs:

Given a connected bipartite graph $G = (A \cup B, E)$, a ***vertex cover*** is a set $S$ of vertices such that every edge has some endpoint in $S$.

Note that $A$ and $B$ are vertex covers. A ***non-trivial vertex cover*** is a vertex cover which does not contain $A$ and does not contain $B$.

A set $F \subseteq E$ of edges ***intersects*** a vertex cover $S$ if the set $E[S] \cap F$ is not empty. That is, if there is an edge $e=(u,v) \in F$ such that both $u$ and $v$ are in $S$.

I decided to call a set of edges which intersect all non-trivial vertex covers, a ***VC cover***.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to find a minimum cardinality VC cover?

Comment: I think you should work a bit more on your definitions. The problem stated as it is now is trivial: since $A$ is a vertex cover, a VC cover $F$ has non-empty intersection with $E[A]$. But $E[A]$ is empty.

Comment: I guess it should be "which intersects all minimal vertex covers" or perhaps "which intersects all vertex covers of minimum cardinality".

Comment: Minimal: same problem, just take $A' \subseteq A$ minimal.
Minimum cardinality could work. Let's wait for the OP clarification.

Comment: hi, I changed the question a bit. I intended that a VC cover should intersect all 
*non-trivial* vertex covers. The set A is a trivial vertex cover.

Comment: Same problem: if either $A$ or $B$ is not minimal, you have $S\subsetneq A$ (or $\subsetneq B$) that is a non trivial vertex cover and $E[S] = \emptyset$. Otherwise, both $A$ and $B$ are minimal. By minimality of $B$, there exists $x \in A$ of degree $1$. Let $y \in B$ be its only neighbor. Since $A$ is minimal, $y$ is also of degree $1$ (othw you could remove $x$ from $A$ and still be a VC). Thus $S'=A \setminus \{x\} \cup \{y\}$ is a non-trivial VC with $E[S'] = \emptyset$.

Comment: @holf I don’t understand your argument. For example, if $|A|,|B|\ge2$ and $G$ is the complete bipartite graph, then  $A$ and $B$ are both minimal vertex covers, but there is no vertex of degree $1$. In general, $A$ is a minimal vertex cover if and only if there are no isolated vertices in $A$, and similarly for $B$.

Comment: You are right of course, you need the whole $A$ to cover $A$ if you only allow vertices there. I was trying to cover only the vertices in $B$...

Comment: Just to check my understanding of the problem, in the case that $|A|=|B|$ and $E=A\times B$, then the (minimal) non-trivial vertex covers are the sets of the form $A\cup\{b\}$ such that $b\in B$, or $\{a\}\cup B$ such that $a\in A$, and the minimum-cardinality VC covers are the perfect matchings in $G$?

Comment: No, the vertex covers you gave are trivial vertex covers because they contain A or contain B. In a complete bipartite graph, you can actually see that there are no non-trivial vertex covers, as any vertex cover must contain A or B (note that the graph is connected). Hope this clarifies things